# How to implement a popup on Android?

Tags: android, popup

I've seen a bunch of application where holding down an entry on an ListView for a bit (longer than a click) produces a popup.  It typically lists the actions to take on the entry (edit, delete, etc...).

Is this something that's built into Android or something I have to build on my own?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean [this UI pattern](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/quick-actions)?

Comment: @alextsc I don't need it that fancy, but yes, that's close enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Dialog (there's a lot of documentation about Android dialogs, you can start here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html ). Or, you can start another activity, which to me seems more Android-friendly, although it might just be a feeling.

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous poster said you can create a Dialog, and that long click you mentioned can be implemented using a [`setOnItemLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener%29). Good luck!

(Edited listener from longclick to itemlongclick)

Answer (score 1):

Holding an entry a bit longer will trigger a context menu.

Use this in onCreate:

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

then override:

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        int idcompte = mComptes.get(info.position).getId();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case DELETE_ID:
                DBhelper dBhelper = new DBhelper(this);
                dBhelper.open();
                dBhelper.deleteCompte(idcompte);
                dBhelper.close();
                onResume();
                return true;

            case EDIT_ID:

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddorupdateCompteActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(AddorupdateCompteActivity.ID, idcompte);
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Above suggestions don't look like the most straightforward approach to me. Just as a ListView has a `setOnItemSelectedListener`, there is an equivalent for long clicks, called [`setOnItemLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemLongClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener%29).

If you combine this listener with `onContextItemSelected` (as illustrated by Noureddine AMRI) for your actual context menu, you've got everything you need. Implementation examples are widespread.